# I need to mathematics printout but this printout gave me datatypes so i cant pass next step

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I need to mathematics printout but this printout gave me datatypes so i cant pass next step.

[I want to take this printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU5Nc.png)

[But I took this printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPcil.png)

```
def anomaliTespiti(df, ozellik):
     outlier_indices = []

     for c in ozellik:
          # 1. Çeyrek
          Q1 = np.percentile(df[c], 25) #Yüzdelik Dilim
          # 3. Çeyrek
          Q3 = np.percentile(df[c], 75)
          #IQR = Inter Quartile Range (Çeyrekler Açıklığı)
          IQR = Q3 - Q1
          # Aykırı değer için ek adım miktarı
          outlier_step = 1.5 * IQR
          #Aykırı değeri ve de bulunduğu indexi tespit edelim.
          outlier_list_col = ozellik[(df[c] < Q1 - outlier_step) | (df[c] > Q3 + outlier_step)].index
          #Koşulun ilk kısmı negatif değerleri kapsarken ikinci kısmı pozitif değerleri kapsar.
          #Tespit edilen indeksleri depolayalım.
          outlier_indices.append(outlier_list_col)

          #Eşsiz aykırı değerleri bulalım.
          outlier_indices = Counter(outlier_indices)
          #Eğer bir örnek v adet sütunda farklı değer ise bunu aykırı kabul edelim.
          multiple_outliers = list(i for i, v in outlier_indices.items() if v > 1)

          return multiple_outliers
     
veri_anomali = veri.loc[anomaliTespiti(veri, ["yas", "kilo", "boy"])]
veri_anomali.spor.value_counts()
```